# Any difference between :model and :model_id in attr_accessible for Rails/ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scaffolding

When I create a scaffold and I need to have a `belongs_to` relation to another model, I add a field called `model_id` (replacing model with that model's name):

```
rails generate scaffold Grade user_id:integer subject_id:integer letter:string
```

Then in the above `Grade` model, I might add:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :subject
```

Rails automatically adds `user_id` and `subject_id` to the list of `attr_accessible` fields. Do I do any harm by also adding `:user` and `:subject` to the list of `attr_accessible` fields so that I can mass assign using those as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attr_accessible is intended to protect against mass-assignment attacks that come from data that is externally sent to your application. In most cases you're probably doing things like this in your create & update actions:

```
@model = Model.new(params[:model])
or
@model.update_attributes(params[:model])
```

You should ask yourself why you'd have one form that uses subject_id and another that uses subject. The only real harm here is inconsistency, which can actually be pretty detrimental to large projects. If you follow the convention that all forms will use the actual database column (subject_id), then you'll save yourself some headache in the future when you can't remember out why you did it two different ways.

If you're updating attributes through the console, you can either use `update_attributes(params[:model], without_protection: true)` or a gem I wrote called [sudo_attributes](https://github.com/beerlington/sudo_attributes) which lets you do `sudo_update_attributes(params[:model])`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't hurt you, but will bring a kind of mess in your code